# How to get coordinates near to specific coordinate using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, rubygems, coordinates

I have a RoR app which has a feature allowing users to add markers in a google maps. This markers are saved in a model that have latitude and longitude attributes.

Supposing that an user placed and saved a marker in a specific location, Stonehenge for example, how can I verify if have any other markers in 250 meters radius of Stonehenge?

Any help will be really appreciated!
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the geocoder gem.  It can convert addresses to lat/lon and ties into active record to do "find me things near this thing" queries.

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/